# what to do if this shown "The display: block property prevents align-items from having an effect. Try setting display to something other than block"

Tags: codeblocks

what to do if this shown "The display: block property prevents align-items from having an effect. Try setting display to something other than block"

[visual Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMuQZ.png)

Please Help to resolve it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.